# jQuery Selector Looping with Variable Variables

Tags: jquery, variables, selector

I've got a jSON ajax response like the following example:

```
['PostA1'] =>1
['PostA2'] =>1
['PostA3'] =>2
['PostB1'] =>1
['PostB2'] =>3
['PostB3'] =>0
['PostB4'] =>2
['Pre1'] =>1
['Pre2'] =>2
['Pre3'] =>1
['Pre4'] =>3
['Pre4'] =>3
```

PostA-x, PostB-x and Pre data refers to sets of radio buttons which need to be set depeing on their value. I could just do this by writing a line of code to process each individual one such as:

```
$("input[id='Pre1-" + data.Pre1 + "']").attr('checked','checked');
$("input[id='Pre1-" + data.Pre2 + "']").attr('checked','checked');
$("input[id='PostA1-" + data.PostA1+ "']").attr('checked','checked');
$("input[id='PostA2-" + data.PostA2 + "']").attr('checked','checked');
```

...etc..., but ideally I'd like to be able to loop through the data set something like...

```
        i = 1;
        $.each("--Aray which starts with PostA--" + i){
              $("input:radio[id='PostA-" + data.PostA -- incrementer variable -- + "'].attr('checked',checked');
i++;
    }
```

then repeat this loop for each of the three data set...but I'm really stuck as firstly I'm not that great at jQuery selectors and secondly I don't know how to make variable variables within the selector.

Hopefully this makes sense! If you guys have any advice on how to do this (maybe I'm going about this totally the wrong way?!?!?) then it'd be greatly appreciated.

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `for..in` to loop the object.

```
for (var key in data) {
  // $("input[id='" + key + "-" + data[key]+ "']").prop('checked', true);
  // below is better if select by id
  $('#'+key+'-'+data[key]).prop('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not iterate over `data` instead? You can use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to do that, and build the current element's id from each key/value pair:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $("#" + key + "-" + value).prop("checked", true);
});
```